# Conditional joint probability-limits of integration

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose we want calculate the joint probability using double or triple integrals (depending on the problem) and a condition is defined as  ***$P(x|y =0.5)$***

Do we plug this value into the function and exclude integration?

We are assuming all the boundaries of integration for all random variables have been define: a<x<b , c<y<d, ....etc)

Comment: There are various issues here, such as inconsistency between $a<x<b$ and $b<y<x$.  You can sometimes also have a risk of a  Borel–Kolmogorov paradox if you condition on an event of probability $0$.  So it may depend on the precise question you are asking

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is called marginalization. In this case, for the sum of two continuous rvs,  $Y=X_1 +X_2$,
$$
P(Y<y) = P(X_1+X_2<y) = \int_{-\infty}^{y}P(X_1+X_2<y|X_1=x_1)P(X_1 = x_1)dx_1
$$
Here $P(X_1 = x_1) = f_{X_1}(x_1)$ is the density of $X_1$.